# Android - how to update ListView item that is currently displayed

Tags: android, listview

I have list of items in my activity which I load dynamically, item after item. 
Initially I load "lightweight" version and when processing is done I want to update the item with new information. Like set some text or replace an image.
That means I need to update what `ListView` item is displaying after `Adapter#getView` already returns. Of course I don't know if user is actively scrolling and this item is still visible or has been scrolled out ot view. 
The only thing I can think of is to extend View so it performs some operations on it's own thread and updates itself when done,but will it work?
Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This android-developers example may be helpful: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 1):

code is:

```
dataAdapter.remove(dataAdapter.getItem(clickedpos));     
dataAdapter.insert(t.getText().toString(), clickedpos);
```

delete previous item on that position and add new item to that position