# Clear cache listview android

Tags: android, list, android-listview

Ara>Button,Dizi>array.

when i clicked button list the botton of list view? is there any body help me?
Help,help

ps: i tried something but not worked

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Ara = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAra);
            multitv =(MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.multiAutoCompleteTextView1);
            adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, Neresi());
            multitv.setAdapter(adapter);

            multitv.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

            Aranan = (String)multitv.getText().toString();
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
           Ara.setOnClickListener(this) ;

        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnAra)
        {

            String []dizi =null;
            dizi = Belirtiler("Baş");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,dizi);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

    }
```

Comment: if you want update your list just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` instead of `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` in `onClick()` method

Comment: I tried but does not work :( i wanna clear listview items before, only show new item on listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for refreshing list see the following link

[How to refresh Android listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)

[Android Updating ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486107/android-updating-listview)

[Android: how to refresh ListView contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903758/android-how-to-refresh-listview-contents)