# How can prevent show a view in custom cursor adapter without re query

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I Use custom cusrsor adapter for ListView.

I want known how can prevent show a view (row) without using changeCursor, swapCursor or requery.(only local)

For example: if(mylist.contains(position)) skip row;

Please help me, Thanks so much

Comment: what do you actually wanna do?

Comment: @pskink I want skip showing a view (row) in cursor adapter. with condition

Comment: do you want to filter-out some rows?

Comment: @pskink, Yes.. for example: if(mylist.contains(position)) skip row;

Comment: and whats wrong with changeCursor/swapCursor? they are used to update the list view's content...

Comment: @pskink, Because I want to keep the another changes and i want it done locally

Comment: sorry, i dont know what you mean

Comment: @pskink Ok thanks np :( , This question how?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591184/ignore-item-view-type-not-worked-in-custom-cursor-adapter

Comment: if you want some tricky Cursor filtering see CursorWrapper class

Comment: @pskink, Thank you very much. If you can answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29605280/how-to-hide-only-one-record-with-cursorwrapper

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Updating ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486107/android-updating-listview)

Answer (score 1):

try like this. 
You might be using some array to populate your data on listview.
remove that element from array and refresh adapter.

If you want to hide 4th item.

```
yourDataArray.remove(3);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: it not correct work ... not release free space on listview or not calculate scroll size again :(

Comment: I don't use  array for populate data... i use cursor and cursor not have remove methode :(  must skip view

Comment: @MehdiEsmaeili use CursorWrapper then

Comment: ok... if possible do not pass cursor directly... first fill the data outside adapter  to a array. And then use that array for adapter. so you can control data flow effectively